# Modelling a hierarchical structure with optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

### Context

My problem is industry-specific but I will explain using an investor/project/charity assignment example.

Typical use case will be a 2K projects (possible investment) managed by 50 charities, and around 20K investors.

- Project: Each project needs a set amount of money, no less but *no more*. So each project has a specific cost. (A typical cost would be 10,000). Each project is managed by a charity.
- Charity: an entity who takes care of a group of projects. A charity also needs a fixed amount of money to run, no less but no more.

  - A charity gets money from everyone who invested in at least one of their projects. So the set of people giving to the charity is the union of the sets of people giving to their projects.
- Investors: Each investor can only invest by a set amount of money into any one project, no more, no less. This fixed investment amount is specific to the investor. They don't have to invest in anything.

  - An investor can invest into as many project as they like (no money limitation), but only by the fixed investment amount. (A typical investment amount would be 5, so it takes a lot of investors to match the cost of one project).
  - An investor also gives their investment amount when they give money to a charity.
- Constraints: all projects and all charities should be exactly funded. If not possible, then priority should be given to exact charity funding.

The only think we can change on is who invests in which project. Investors do **not** invest directly into charities, which is what makes it tricky. They invest in a charity by investing into one of their projects. Even if they invest in more than one of their projects, they will only fund the charity once...

### Example

- Investor A can invest 5.
- Investor B can invest 10.
- Investor C can invest 5.
- Project 1 costs 10.
- Project 2 costs 5.
- Project 3 costs 5.
- Charity A runs project 1, and requires 10.
- Charity B runs project 2 and 3, and requires 20.

The output could be:

- Investor B invests in project 1 (cost achieved).
- Investor A invest in project 2 (cost achieved).
- Investor B and C invest in project 3 (too much! but needed for charity funding).
- Charity A receives money from investor A only:

  - 10 funding received (ok).
- Charity B receives money from investors A, B and C:

  - 20 funding received (ok).

### Model

[image: Modelling idea #1]

Here I would have 2K x 20K planning entities, which is a lot.

### Questions

My questions are:

- Will it work? Especially since the charity funding is not explicit, how can I make the planner understand that e.g. to remove someone from the charity, they need to be removed from all the charity's projects?
- Above I present only projects and charity, but in my actual problem I have more than just charities. For example, imagine the projects are each in one of the 5 continents, and the rule for giving funding to continent are the same than for charities. The additional constraint would be to reach the specified funding per continent... Which may or may not conflict with the charity funding...

EDIT:
- I went ahead with my first model, my questions are still outstanding

Comment: Try applying the domain design guidelines of docs section [4.3.1. Is This Class a Problem Fact or Planning Entity?](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#isThisClassAProblemFactOrPlanningEntity).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it convinced me that my first model was the way to go. I edited my post and I hope you can answer my questions.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Forgot to ping you